# How is the Ubuntu default mono font file created?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, default

When I was running Ubuntu 16.04 I worked on an app which used astrological symbols such as Aries ♈︎.  I have just discovered that these signs now display like this: ♈

After a bit of research I think this is what happened: When I installed 20.04, it seems that a new default mono font file was created, containing the colored characters.  I am guessing that the default file is created by looking at various font files and combining them, and one of them must have contained the colored characters.

My immediate particular need is to get back to a font file like the one I used to have with no colored characters.  Can anyone advise me how to do this?

More general questions: Just how is the default file created?  What files should I set up in what directories if I want them included in the default mono font file? How to modify an existing default mono font file?

Thank you.

Roger House
Software Developer